# Excel Pivot Table with "Measure"

Tags: excel, pivot-table, measure

I want to use the pivottable feature of excel to solve my below issue.
I have two tables as follows:

#### Table= A_Master

[image]

#### Table= A_Child

[image]

Where table `A_Master` Joins with table `A_Child` on `Student Name` in pivot table relationship.
The final table has to be like below:

[image]

Here I dont know how to create `"Measure" = "FeesRemaining"` so that it calculates ActualFees-FeesPaid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the difference between what the actually fee is minus the sum of everything they paid in the other table. Not sure if  there is a better way to do it but this is one way to do it.

```
= CALCULATE(
    SUM(Master[Actual Fees]),
    FILTER(Master, 'Master'[Student Name] = VALUES('Master'[Student Name]))
) - CALCULATE(
    SUM(Child[Fees Paid]),
    FILTER(Child,'Child'[StudentName] = VALUES('Master'[Student Name]))
)
```

The measure above gets a sum of all the fees that are owed by the student in that row of the master table, then subtracts the sum of everything that was paid by that student in the child table.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I found some easy solution:
SUM(ActualFees)
-SUM(FeesPaid)